# Getting authenticationerror.login_cookie_required error while using Google adwords API with Python

Tags: python, soap, google-ads-api

I am trying to use python to consume some adwords soap API, I am able to get the auth token but when I try to make a get request I got the authenticationerror.login_cookie_required error. Any ideas?

```
from suds.client import Client

auth_data = {'accountType':'GOOGLE', 'Email':'xxx@xxx.com', 'Passwd':'xxxxxxxx', 'service':'adwords', 'source':'xxxxxxxxxx'}
auth_data = urllib.urlencode(auth_data)
auth_request = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', auth_data)
auth_response = urllib2.urlopen(auth_request)
auth_response = auth_response.read()
split = auth_response.split('=')
auth_token = split[len(split)-1]

url = 'https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
authToken = auth_token
developerToken = 'xxx@xxx.com++NZD'
userAgent = 'jameslin-python'
client.set_options(soapheaders=(authToken,developerToken,userAgent))
client.service.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Python client library for the AdWords API?
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/

Comment: Yes, that worked, but I was trying to use the soap service directly

Answer (score 0):

authToken isn't a SOAP header. RequestHeader is the soap header and authToken is a member of that header. See http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/headers.html and http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/#soap for more details.

I also wish to point out that AdWords API official forum is http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api, where we regularly answer questions on AdWords API. If you have any followup questions, feel free to ask on the official forum.

Cheers,
Anash